# SearchBar not working when search button is clicked

Tags: iphone

Can anyone help me out, i am working with UISearchBar and want that when i write anything in SearchBar and press enter key, it will start desired operation...

I have read searchBarSearchButtonClicked function will get called once the “Search” button will be clicked on the pop-up keyboard window. But it is not called:(
I have implemented as:

- (void) searchBarSearchButtonClicked:(UISearchBar*) searchContact
  {
  //do some thing
  }

i have checked by placing breakpoints infact this function is not being called....

any idea??

Thanks!!

Comment: Check in IB UISearchBar's outlet is connected or not. Tell me the superview of UISearchBar? And also check the delegate methods.

Comment: Make sure you have connected the searchbar outlet correctly and also search bar delegate.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Did you assign delegate to that viewcontroller which implemented "searchBarSearchButtonClicked" ?

You need to assign delegate like this.

```
searchBar.delegate =self;
```

Comment: thanx Deep that was what i was missing:)

Comment: I am glad that resolved your problem. mark as Answer please so other should use this as well. Thanks

Comment: +1 @iphone developer, if it works then you need to accept it . you can accept an answer after 15 minutes.

Comment: You can see Tick mark sign right side below up and down arrow. You just need to tick on that and you are done.

Answer (score 3):

You need to implement the  `UISearchBarDelegate` protocol and set the delegate of the textfield to the class which implements this protocol.

This is the reason why the delegate is not getting called.

You can try this,

In IB set the delegate to file's owner and implement the delegate.

In Code, if you hold reference to the search bar, then on viewDidLoad

```
searchBar.delegate = self;
```